# Checkable Checkbox inside layout that represent every item of List/Grid-view

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, checkbox, android-event

I have the following layout for items that fill my GridView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/favor_border"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<CheckBox
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:id="@+id/isFavoriteCheckBox"
    android:button="@drawable/btn_star_selector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:clickable="false"/>

    <!--Other elements--> 
</LinearLayout>
```

**What I need** is to handle clicks on every GridView item (knowing selected item Id) **and** handle clicks (checks actually) on *isFavoriteCheckbox* in different way.

**What I've tried**:

1. I've subscribed on GridView's *OnItemClick* event and in handler I know which Gridview's item was clicked. But I don't know what particular UI element of selected item was clicked.
2. I've subscribed on *isFavoriteCheckbox*'s *OnClick* event and in handler I know when checkbox was clicked but don't know which one exactly.

**Required layout** (Checkboxes should be checkable):
[image]